# Where can I get the Dragon King Sword?

Tags: fantasy-life

Pam keeps asking me for CRAZY things! I want help. Can anyone tell me where to get some of her crazy stuff? I'm short on Luneres coins and I really want some to get the Dragon King Sword.

Also, does anyone know where I can find the Tsunami Talisman?

Comment: My fist request is where to find Tsunami Talisman x1. Have DLC...

Comment: Welcome to the site.. unfortunately this is not a forum. It is possible someone will look up a list of all the crazy stuff the person can ask for but if you can put a full list in the question then you can get a more exact answer. Adding items as you run into them into the comments is likely just to get you down voted.

Comment: Please, take the [Tour for the site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and also read [ask]. Adding comments instead of editing question is not the proper way to get more information into the question. Since this is a Questions and Answers site, don't put a "signature" into all the questions and answers you write.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fantasy Life wiki](http://fantasy-life.wikia.com/), the Dragon King's Sword may be obtained **using Gold Lunares Coins at Castele's Goddess Statue**. There does not seem to be any other way, as far as the wiki concerns.

[image: Dragon King's Sword]

As for the Tsunami Talisman, it's possible to make this item using a recipe that can be obtained from completing Life Master Flamel's special request once reaching God rank in the Alchemist life.